# Average of a variable based on grouping of frequencies of another variable (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset that contains an enum variable (let's say, School Name) that I want to create an arbitrary bucketing of the count of, and another continuous variable (let's say, test score) that I would like to include in analysis, based on the arbitrary bucketing.

E.g.

```
school_name  test_score  student_id
washington      97         11112
adams           99         11113
jefferson       78         11114
washington      85         11115
washington      88         11116
monroe          75         11117
monroe          77         11118
monroe          68         11119
```

**I would like to find the average test score based on the size of schools (e.g. small, med, large schools) - ideally in a single query**.

I don't have a variable for number of students in the school in my data, so I need to create that by grouping on school name and arbitrarily creating buckets (e.g. small schools have <100 students, med schools 101-500, etc).

The ideal result would look like:

```
School_size  Avg_score
Small         87
Med           89
Large         88
```

Many thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using two levels of aggregation.  If I understand correctly:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN cnt < 100 THEN 'small' 
             WHEN cnt < 500 THEN 'medium'
             ELSE 'Large'   
        END) as School_size,
       SUM(sum_score) / SUM(cnt) asAvg_score
FROM (SELECT school_name,count(*) as cnt,
             SUM(test_score) as sum_score
      FROM t
      GROUP BY school_name  
     ) s
GROUP BY school_size;
```

I'm pretty sure any solution requires two levels of aggregation.  So, I think this is likely to be the fastest solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to get student amount by `school_name` in a subquery, then use `CASE WHEN` to split the school size and get `Avg_score`.

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN cnt <100 then 'small' 
         WHEN cnt between 101 and 500 then 'Med'
         ELSE 'Large'   
    END) School_size,AVG(avgScore) Avg_score
FROM (
    SELECT school_name,count(*) cnt,AVG(test_score) avgScore
    FROM T
    group by school_name  
) t1
group by 
CASE WHEN cnt <100 then 'small' 
     WHEN cnt between 101 and 500 then 'Med'
     ELSE 'Large'   
END
```

Comment: Why not just group by school_size?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
 SELECT SCHOOLSIZE,AVG(test_score) FROM TABLE T
   JOIN 
   (
     SELECT SCHOOLNAME,
            CASE WHEN  COUNT(1) < 100 THEN 'SMALL' 
                 WHEN  COUNT(1) BETWEEN 101 AND 500 THEN 'MED'
            END AS SCHOOLSIZE
     FROM TABLE 
     GROUP BY SCHOOLNAME
   ) AS S 
 ON S.SCHOOLNAME = T.SCHOOLNAME
 GROUP SCHOOLSIZE
```